# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at bundle.js:1:1) // REACT JS

Tags: json, reactjs

estoy aprendiendo React js pero me salta este error en la consola. Les comparto el codigo del index.html aparte no tengo una carpeta bundle.js:1:1 que menciona el error.
En cuanto al punto rojo de la carpeta src/ no creo que sea ya que anteriormente me ha estado corriendo con ese warning.

Gracias de antemano,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <!-- <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />-->
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: carpetas]

Comment: Cómo estás corriendo la aplicacion?

Comment: por la terminal: You can now view c in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3001/RaquelReedemed/react-practic
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.80:3001/RaquelReedemed/react-practic

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully

Comment: disculpa ya corrio, llame de nuevo el npm start en la terminal . Nose porq pasa esto :/ . Me gustaria entender para q no me pase de nuevo u_u

Comment: Quizas fue un error al crear el build de la aplicación. Si la pregunta ya fue resuelta te recomendaría que agregues una respuesta con la solución que encontraste, o que la elimines si es que ya no es relevante. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Estaba haciendo el npm start en una terminal diferente donde la hice la primera vez, y por eso me dio el error. Una vez aplique el npm start en la misma terminal corrio. Saludos!